# How to create a client notification service for a webapp or should I use an Observer Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dao, observer-pattern

I have a fully implemented DAO and all my beans inherit an Entity object.
Now, I want to create a client notification system whereby, when a user creates/updates/delete an entity to/from a persistence storage, a notification is automatically sent to the client via email.

I have a DAO manager that uses a Factory Pattern to return to me a manager of the DAO based on the entity type.

```
e.g EntityManager manager = EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(Product.class);
```

each manager has a create(), remove(), update() method....

My first idea is to have all my entity managers inherit an Observer interface and after the function calls (create, remove, update, etc.) a notification is sent.

Is that a wise idea? If not, what can I do in order to send a notification to client?

I'm running JBoss 5 or Tomcat 6 (or both for easy deployment) and Apache Struts (though I don't see the reason why I mentioned it).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PS. I've checked this comment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001073/one-dao-per-thread-or-threadsafe-dao). Should I make my DAO thread safe? It's basically an online store I'm creating for a client.

Comment: What persistence framework do you use?

Comment: None, I took the liberty of writing my own DAO instead of using a Framework like Hibernate.

Comment: Note that JPA (and Hibernate) have built in `EntityListeners` with callback methods for that.

Comment: I read about it. Can I integrate Hibernate's EntityListeners to my DAO?

Comment: ah, you are not using JPA at all. Just the names of the classes are the same. Look at Drew Wills answer

Comment: If it's not possible to create an entity listener, I can easily move to Hibernate (seeing that I have all entities done already), it's just mapping to hibernate and boom....(i hope). :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to allow your entity managers to remain blissfully unaware of who needs to be notified and how to send them emails.  This approach will improve maintenance of both the existing manager code and the messaging code you intend to write, and will pay off hugely if you ever need to write new entity managers what store your entities in JCR or tranmit them via web services, etc.

Comment: Ok, Interesting suggestion. How would I use a decorator exactly in this scenario? I know what you're saying, but is it possible to add it without me having to change my structure already?

Comment: It's possible to add it without changes to existing code if you either (1) use an IoC container or (2) some flavor of factory pattern to define the EntityManager impl in use within your system.